# How to call actionStatus in javascript onchange event?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, actionstatus

I want to show loading image on change of a selectlist value. Already 3 javascript functions is being called during onchange event, hence actionSupport is not working when onchange event is used.
I used actionFunction but it seems to be not working:-

```
    <apex:selectList id="competnsId" value="{!fieldSet.field2.value}"                   
        rendered="{!fieldSet.field2.fieldType=='PICKLIST'}"                                       
        multiselect="false" size="1" onchange="javascript:loadImage();searchButtonClicked();showBusyDialog();onToggleResetLink();">  
        <apex:selectOption itemValue="" itemLabel="<i>{!fieldSet.field2.label}</i>" itemEscaped="false" />  
        <apex:selectOptions id="compOpts" value="{!fieldSet.field2.pickListValues}" />
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" status="waitStatus" reRender="theForm" />  


</apex:selectList>'

 <apex:actionFunction name="loadImage"  status="waitStatus" reRender="theForm"/>
```

Comment: `<apex:actionFunction name="loadImage"  status="waitStatus" reRender="theForm"/>` where is your action attribute ? it should be like `<apex:actionFunction name="loadImage"  status="waitStatus" reRender="theForm" action="{!methodName}"/>`  same for `<apex:actionSupport>`

Comment: I don't need action attribute as i'm not doing any logic or processing in my controller. I just want to call actionStatus & show the loading image.

Comment: then use jquery loading instead actinstatus http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/

Comment: I do not agree, Ratan. Using an actionSupport will also submit the form (or actionRegion) to the controller, and there's no reason not to use it if you don't need an action. I'd rather remove all other "normal" onchange events than get rid of the actionSupport. As for the question; just to be sure, if you remove the onchange attrbute on the selectList, does it work? Could you maybe move all of those functions to the oncomplete of onbeforedomupdate of the actionSupport?

Comment: Thanks Lex, your solution worked. I moved all remaining onchange functions to onbeforedomupdate. Only issue is there is a lag of 2 secs when results are loaded after the image stops loading.